# Transfer parameters from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I created sliding tabs like described in [Sliding Tabs](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) and want to use the transfered data for further stuff.
I searched for solutions, but everytime the values are empty.

I used the following code in my Activity. The Fragment is called tab1_simplecall and the ID of the framelayout is tab1_fragment:

```
if (findViewById(R.id.tab1_fragment) != null){
        if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
            return;
        }
        tab1 = new tab1_simplecall();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tab1_fragment, tab1);
    }

Fragment fragObj = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("ID", ID);
bundle.putString("time", time);
bundle.putString("worker", worker);
fragObj.setArguments(bundle);
```

In my Fragment i try to receive the data:

```
 private void loadBundle() {
            Bundle b = getArguments();
            Log.i("tab1", "Check if b != null");
            if (b != null) {
                    String name= b.getString("name");
                    Integer ID= b.getInt("ID");
                    String date= b.getString("date");
                    Log.i("tab1 Übergabe: ", "" + name+ " " + ID+ " " + date);
            }
            else
            {
                    Log.i("tab1", "B = null");
            }
    }
```

But every time, the bundle b is null. How can I solve that issue?

Comment: How are you attaching your fragment to your app? Fragment Transactions? Could you edit your question and include that line of code?

Comment: Sry, i'm not sure, what you exactly want :/

Comment: You've instantiated a `Fragment` object, but somewhere in your code you had to attach that fragment to a container frame. Could you post that line?

Comment: I think that is the missing part. How should that look like?

Comment: I've added a code snippet regarding the attachment, but it's still not working.

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you're actually using? Look, at this code you've posted you are first adding a instance of the fragment named `tab1_simplecall` to your frame, and after that you're instantiating a new `Fragment` object that stays untouched. Do you see your mistake? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharedPreference for sending data between activities or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the following code to the end of my onCreate in the activity. Now the data will be transfered. Thank you so far :)

```
 if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        tab1 = new tab1_simplecall();
        bundle.putString("ID", "345123");
        tab1.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.tab1_fragment, tab1).commit();
    }
```

But several milliseconds later, the app crashes with the message "IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id ... for fragment ...

Snippet from my layout for the tab:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tab1_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp">
```

In my Activity i call the id (tab1_fragment) of the fragment in my Fragmentlayout. But why? :(